# Replacing dynamic content from within dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to set up a basic site which calls content into a specific section of one page from the same section of another page and updates the url without reloading common elements.

I have been cribbing off of the [CSS-Tricks example](http://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/) updated early last year and it works fine as a single-level navigation, but what I want to do is call a secondary navigation into the dynamic content area, which will then link to child pages. So the secondary nav is calling new content into the same section it is currently occupying.

The problem is that the secondary nav breaks the script every other time it is clicked, causing a full page reload. Not every time, every OTHER time. I would guess there is some condition which is toggling between true and false each time the secondary nav is activated but my js skills are lacking and my usual method of fiddling with the code until it somehow works hasn't panned out.

If anyone has any insight into why this is happening and how to fix it, it would be very much appreciated. I have a test example set up [here](http://6ft6design.com/6ft6-dynamictest/) if anyone wants to check it out.

Parent page, where "guts" is the target div for content replacement:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><h2><a href="index.html">Home</a></h1></li>
      <li><h2><a href="about.html">About</a></h1></li>
      <li><h2><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></h1></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section id="main-content">
  <div id="guts">
    <h1>Landing page with sub-navigation. Nav bg is gray on page load.</h1>
    <nav id="sub-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><h3><a href="example1.html">Sub-Nav Link</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="example2.html">Other Sub-Nav Link</a></h3></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Child page:

```
<header>
  <nav id="sub-one">
    <ul>
      <li><h2><a href="index.html">Home</a></h1></li>
      <li><h2><a href="about.html">About</a></h1></li>
      <li><h2><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></h1></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section id="main-content">
  <div id="guts">
    <h1>First sub-page via sub-nav. If top nav bg changed to green, the whole page was reloaded.</h1>
    <nav id="sub-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><h3><a href="example1.html">Sub-Nav Link</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="example2.html">Other Sub-Nav Link</a></h3></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

js:

```
$(function() {

    if(Modernizr.history){

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
        $el;

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        _link = $(this).attr("href");
        history.pushState(null, null, _link);
        loadContent(_link);
        return false;
    });

    function loadContent(href){
        $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(href + " #guts", function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200);
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        console.log(href);
                        $("nav a[href$="+href+"]").addClass("current");
                    });
                });
    }

    $(window).bind('popstate', function(){
       _link = location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''); //get filename only
       loadContent(_link);
    });

} // otherwise, history is not supported, so nothing fancy here.


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.delegate()`, the element that you bind to has to be static, the selector for the dynamic element is in the arguments. `$("nav").delegate()` works for the first-level navigation, but the send-level navigation is loaded dynamically, so the bindings won't work for that. You need to bind to a static element:

```
$mainContent.on("click", "nav a", function() {
    ...
});
```

BTW, `.delegate()` has been superceded by `.on()` as of jQuery 1.7. They're equivalent, but the arguments are in a different order.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply! Looks like you hit the nail on the head regarding targeting static vs dynamic content. I didn't have any success converting `.delegate()` to `.on()`, but after some trial and error I found that calling the function one way for the static first level nav and the other for second level has got things working.
Not sure if this is totally efficient or if it breaks any rules but it seems to have solved my issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Scratch the part about `.delegate()` vs `.on()`, I just realized my example was linking to an older version of jquery.

Comment: That was going to be my guess.

Comment: One last thing... Updating the jquery library (1.4 > 2.1.3) seems to break the add/remove `.current` function, which highlights the appropriate nav element for each page. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: It seems very unlikely that here would be a change in how `.addClass` and `.removeClass` work in the new version. Make sure you don't have the `.` in the class name when you call these methods.

Comment: I searched around some similar questions on this site and found an example with the correct/new syntax for the part that identifies the new active nav element: `$("nav a[href='"+href+"']")` -- single quotes wrapping the double quotes did the trick. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: I guess you have some special chacters in the `href` that were causing problems, and needed to be quoted.